# Ad-Valorem Tax - which curves change?

Tags: microeconomics, monopoly

I've been asked :
Consider an ad-valorem tax on the price of a monopoly’s good. This tax reduces the net
price received by the monopoly from the price the consumer pays p to p(1-t) where 0 < t < 1
is the proportional tax rate.
(a) Show that with a linear demand curve of the form p(y) =a-by(a,b>0) and constant
marginal cost that the introduction of the tax causes a rise in price less than the full
extent of the tax.

Which of the curves change and why (inverse demand, MC,MR)